# Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer could not obtain keys for Reader Role user

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure Storage Account and want to grant read access to a colleague. All identities are in the same Azure Active Directory so it was easy to add him to the "Reader" role in the Access Control blade of the Azure portal.

When he opens Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer the subscription and storage account are visible but the node for Blob Containers can't be expanded. Exception says:

> Could not obtain keys for Storage Account. Please check that you have
>   the correct permissions

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is now possible (In preview). Your AD users can be given the "Storage Blob Data Reader" privilege.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-preview-of-aad-authentication-for-storage/

Comment: If you are still seeing the listkeys permission error  even after you have `Storage Blob Data Reader`, you may need to tell it to use AD auth by clicking on `Authentication method: Access key (Switch to Azure AD User Account)` at top of page after viewing a containers contents

Answer (score 6):

This is expected behavior. Essentially to list storage keys, the user should be in a role that allows `listKeys` operation. The built-in `Reader` role does not have permission to perform `listKeys` operation.

The rationale (a bit convoluted though) behind this decision is that a user in `Reader` role should only be able to `Read` and not perform any inserts/updates or deletes. Considering if someone has account key for a storage account, they can do these operations. Thus the user in `Reader` role is not granted permission to list the account keys.

What you could do is create a `Shared Access Signature (SAS)` with read/list permissions and share that SAS URL with your colleague. Then they will be able to access the data in that storage account but won't be able to perform any create/update/delete operations.